# Python - limit the number of padding 0s added to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

How can I format a floating point number such that I limit the number of decimal places to a fixed length, but do not add padding zeros in the case when the number has less decimal places than asked for?

For printing with fixed precision, I would usually do the following:

```
print('{:.3f}'.format(123.4567)) # prints 123.457
```

However for number with less than 3 decimals, it adds padding zeros:

```
print('{:.3f}'.format(123.4)) # prints 123.400
```

What I would like is to have the second version keep the argument unchanged:

```
print('{:.3f}'.other_format(123.4)) # should print 123.4
```

What is a possible method to have the number printed as in the third example?

Thank you!

Comment: try using `g` instead of `f`, although, that might turn it into an exponential.

Comment: but honestly, you can also just do something like `result = '{:.3f}'.format(123.4)` and. `if '.' in result: result = result.rstrip("0")` which is not pretty but might be more reliable

Comment: I think you can just use the `round` function on the number prior to printing it. `number = 124.4` `number = number.round(1)` `print(number)` `output: 124.4`

Comment: @Mouse the OP is not trying to round though

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point, but if you do `print_number = number.round(3)` say, won't this always work for printing a number to 3 decimal places, removing zero padding? Granted, it might be very inefficient for the task at hand

Comment: There is nothing in the number representation to state how many significant digits it has. `123.4` and `123.400` are identical as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually the manual `rstrip`ping does the trick; indeed there seems to be no 'automatic' way to do it, besides rounding (which I would not apply in my particular case). I would accept the `rstrip` comment as a valid answer for my use case.

Comment: @Polb well, `g` does strip trailing non-significant zeros, but it also may use exponential notation

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this (round will cut additional zeros):

```
print(round(123.4, 3))
```

Comment: It's not `round` cutting additional zeros, it's `print`.

Comment: Indeed for the example I have posted, it works fine, but I would rather not `round` the numbers.

Comment: From docs: Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits.
    
    The return value is an integer if ndigits is omitted or None.  Otherwise
    the return value has the same type as the number.  ndigits may be negative.

Comment: @Polb ah ok, you didn't mention it in question :)

Answer (score 0):

It stupid but answers the question

```
print('{:.3f}'.format(123.4)[:-2]) # should print 123.4
```

Comment: you can't rely on a hard-coded number though